# PHP - referencing a $key value in an associative array

Tags: php, xml, arrays, associative-array

```
$XMLproducts = simplexml_load_file("products.xml");
```

Using the simplexml_load_file function, I am creating associative array of links that give the hard drive space of the computers in the XML file below.

```
foreach($XMLproducts->product as $Product) {
$hard_drive[$Product->harddrive] = "<a href='searchResults.php?Keyword=".$keyword."&Harddrive=".$Product->harddrive."'>".$Product->harddrive . "</a>";
}
```

In this for each loop, I need to use the actual numerical value of the hard drive space (IE 200, 100 etc.) in an if statement. How can I reference the numerical amount (found in the 'harddrive' element of the XML file) in the foreach loop below. I assumed the best way to do that would be using the $key variable below. The foreach loop isn't outputting anything - with or without the if statement.

```
foreach($hard_drive as $key => $value) {
if ($key == "200GB") { 
echo $key . " " . $value . "<br>";
}}

<products>

<product type="Desktop">
<name>Desktop 1</name>
<harddrive>200GB</harddrive>
</product>

<product type="Tablet">
<name>Ipad 1</name>
<harddrive>100GB</harddrive>
</product>

<product type="Desktop">
<name>Desktop 2</name>
<harddrive>200GB</harddrive>
</product>

<product type="Tablet">
<name>Ipad 2</name>
<harddrive>80GB</harddrive>
</product>

</products>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to make a little more clear what you're after? Maybe show what your `foreach` loop is outputting and point out specifically what part you're not happy with. I think maybe you're asking how to grab "100" from "100GB", for example, but I'm not certain.

Comment: The foreach loop is not outputting anything

Comment: What do you get if you var_dump($hard_drive); ?

Comment: print_r products: Array ( )

Answer (score 0):

try this?

```
foreach($XMLproducts->product as $Product) {

    echo $Product->name." : ".$Product->harddrive;
    if($Product->harddrive == "100GB"){
        echo " ***";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: I need to display the links from the $hard_drive

Answer (score 0):

There were three things to change -

First, we need to cast the object's properties to strings to use them as keys in an array, using (string).

Second, the way you were generating the array would overwrite wherever two hard drives had the same capacity - they would have the exact same key, thus erasing the data for the first 200GB drive. We can use the object's name as a key, and store the capacity and the hyperlink inside that array element.

Third, just a style decision, I renamed the array $hard_drives.

```
 foreach($XMLproducts->product as $Product) {
    $hd = (string)$Product->harddrive;
    $name = (string)$Product->name;
    $hard_drives[$name]['link'] = "<a href='searchResults.php?Keyword=".$keyword."&Harddrive=".$hd."'>".$hd . "</a>";
    $hard_drives[$name]['capacity'] = $hd;

}

    //echo '<pre>';
    //print_r($hard_drives);
    //echo '</pre>';

foreach($hard_drives as $key => $array) {
    if ($array['capacity'] == "200GB") { 
        echo $key . " " . $array['capacity'] . " " .$array['link']."<br>";
    }
}
```